# Set MP4 thumbnail

Tags: ffmpeg, thumbnails

With
[AtomicParsley](http://atomicparsley.sourceforge.net),
you can set the thumbnail that will be displayed when you look at the file in a file explorer. Example commands

```
$ atomicparsley infile.mp4 --artwork infile.png

$ atomicparsley infile.mp4 -t
Atom "covr" contains: 1 piece of artwork
```

I notice that the artwork shows up as a stream with FFmpeg

```
ffmpeg version N-51639-g7775992 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Apr  5 2013 22:29:42 with gcc 4.8.0 (GCC)
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'A Knight's Tale (2001).mp4':
  Duration: 02:12:08.96, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2364 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p,
                             1280x544 [SAR 1:1 DAR 40:17], 2071 kb/s, 23.98 fps,
                             23.98 tbr, 24k tbn, 47.95 tbc
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, 5.1, fltp,
                             287 kb/s
    Stream #0:2: Video: png, rgb24, 1280x544 [SAR 1:1 DAR 40:17], 90k tbr,
                        90k tbn, 90k tbc
```

So, is it possible to mux in thumbnail artwork using FFmpeg?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54717175/how-do-i-add-a-custom-thumbnail-to-a-mp4-file-using-ffmpeg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with the [TagEditor project](//github.com/Martchus/tageditor). To add:

```
tageditor -s cover=y.jpg --max-padding 125000 -f z.mp4
```

To remove:

```
tageditor -s cover= --max-padding 125000 -f z.mp4
```

Answer (score 6):

Try to use ffmpeg `-disposition` option along with `-map`.

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i image.png -map 0 -map 1 -c copy -c:v:1 png \
-disposition:v:1 attached_pic out.mp4
```

More information can be found in ffmpeg documentation:

- [-map option](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Map)
- [ffmpeg main options](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Main-options)

Also, please note, it's not guaranteed that the image you use will be showed in
a video preview or as a file tumbanail, because different software programs may
not use embedded thumbnails at all.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, but support depends on your container format; mp4 will work but others may not.

```
ffmpeg -i INPUT.mp4 -i IMAGE.png -acodec copy -vcodec copy -map 0 -map 1:0 OUTPUT.mp4
```

Comment: On my system this does not change the default thumbnail, in fact resultant file is left without a thumbnail at all.