# Add poster frame (artwork) to mp4

Tags: ffmpeg

I've tried using [this solution using ffmpeg to set a poster frame](https://superuser.com/a/597953/525112) for an MP4.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i image.png -acodec copy -vcodec copy -map 0 -map 1:0 -metadata comment="adding a comment" output.mp4
```

The metadata is being set, but the image is not being saved. When I inspect this output with `ffprobe -show_format` the movie does contain 3 streams (instead of the old 2 streams), but it thinks it's a video:

```
Stream #0:2(und): Video: png (mp4v / 0x7634706D), rgba(pc), 843x633, 123731 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 12800 tbc
```

Saving the image using a GUI program then inspecting shows

```
Stream #0:2: Video: png, rgb24(pc), 843x633, 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
```

How do I specify the 2nd input is an image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basic syntax with a recent version of ffmpeg is

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i image.png -map 1 -map 0 -c copy -disposition:0 attached_pic out.mp4
```

In the output, ffmpeg will still report the stream as video. Check using your file manager.

Comment: lol, I just found the docs stating the same and was posting when your answer came up, thanks :)

Comment: What version of ffmpeg supports `attached_pic`? The version distributed with Ubuntu 18.04 doesn't seem to support it.

Comment: @CraigMcQueen 4.0 or later.